# App not firing as expected when launched with a deeplink

Tags: ios, deep-linking, branch.io

I am using https://branch.io/ in an iOS app.

I followed the documentation in start.branch.io to set a deeplink.

It works up to a certain point. But I continuously get thrown to Safari and the place on the appStore do download the app, when the app itself should only be fired.

Here is my code just in case:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication*)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary*)launchOptions
{
    Branch *branch = [Branch getInstance];
    [branch initSessionWithLaunchOptions:launchOptions 
              andRegisterDeepLinkHandler:^(NSDictionary *params, NSError *error) {
        if (!error && params && [params objectForKey:@"XP"]) {
            // We do things with the parameter XP!
        }
    }];

    return YES;
}    


- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application continueUserActivity:(NSUserActivity *)userActivity
 restorationHandler:(void (^)(NSArray *restorableObjects))restorationHandler
{
    BOOL handledByBranch = [[Branch getInstance] continueUserActivity:userActivity];

    return handledByBranch;
}
```

What may be wrong in what I did? Somewhere in the settings?
Any tip is welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alex with Branch here: it sounds like your Universal Links configuration isn't complete yet. The guide on start.branch.io needs a bit of revision...my apologies. Give our [main Universal Links setup guide](https://dev.branch.io/getting-started/universal-app-links/overview) a look and let me know if you're still running into trouble!

Comment: Thanks, I finally made it work, and found the trick in the `Troubleshooting Universal Links` section of your documentation, using a long press. If end users happen to be in the same situation: no one will open the link!

Comment: Glad to hear, and I agree — very frustrating situation for users. Hopefully iOS 10 will have a more solid solution!